# if value is selected from dropdown show another div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array that is creating a dropdown list, what I would like to do is if "Other" is selected show another element in the dom which is being hidden until "Other" is selected.

Jquery:

```
specialtyArray = ['One', 'Two','Other']
```

HTML:

```
 <ul class="form-dropdown-ul specialty-ul">
        <li class="specialty-list-item dropdown-list-item" id="specialty-list-item-0" tabindex="0"><label
                class="specialty-radio-label dropdown-label">One</label></li>
        <li class="specialty-list-item dropdown-list-item" id="specialty-list-item-1" tabindex="0"><label
                class="specialty-radio-label dropdown-label">Two</label></li>
        <li class="specialty-list-item dropdown-list-item" id="specialty-list-item-2" tabindex="0"><label
                class="specialty-radio-label dropdown-label">Other</label></li>
    </ul>


<div class="register_input-container--other">
      <input id="other" class="form-input form-input--other" name="other" type="text"
             placeholder="Please specify*">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .register_input-container--other {
      display: none;
  }
```

Comment: a working example of jsfiddle or codepen will quicker in finding a solution

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Include your attempt in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, one with CSS only, the other with Javascript.

**The Css Way**
If you put the a  element inside the `<label>` tag like so

```
<li class="specialty-list-item dropdown-list-item" id="specialty-list-item-2" tabindex="0">
  <label class="specialty-radio-label dropdown-label">
    Other
    <div class="register_input-container--other">
      <input id="other" class="form-input form-input--other" name="other" 
      type="text" placeholder="Please specify*">
    </div>
  </label>
</li>
```

Then you can use css:hover to show the hidden-container, like so

```
.register_input-container--other {
      display: none;
  }

  dropdown-label: hover > .register_input-container--other {
      display: block;
  }
```

**The JS way**
To do this with Javascript(Jquery), you could keep your HTML exactly as it is, and do the following

```
$('#specialty-list-item-2').click(function(){
  $('.register_input-container--other').toggleClass('show');
});
```

For this you would need to add the following class, further down in the css code(for hierarchy).

```
.show {
  display: block
}
```